# Fullcalendar :ERROR Error: viewType "" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins, angular 14

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular14

I'm new to Angular, and I want to display a calendar using the fullCalendar library. I already installed the package I need, and then I created a new calendar component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import { Competition } from 'src/app/model/competition.model';
import { CompetitionService } from 'src/app/services/competition/competition.service';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions;

  constructor(private competitionService: CompetitionService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchCompetitionData();
  }

  fetchCompetitionData(): void {
    this.competitionService.getCompetitionData().subscribe(
      (data: Competition[]) => {
        const events = data.map((d) => ({
          title: d.code,
          date: d.date
        }));
        console.log(data);
        console.log(events);

        this.calendarOptions = {
          plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          events: events
        };
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching competition data:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

in this component i fetch a dynamic data and try to display it in the calendar
for the template , i added this line

```
<full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

i already added the fullcalendqr module to my app.module
but i get this error when i load the page

```
ERROR Error: viewType "" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins
    at an._computeCurrentViewData (index.js:1468:19)
    at an.computeCurrentViewData (internal-common.js:867:37)
    at new an (index.js:1217:36)
    at new Ce (index.js:2036:9)
    at mr.ngAfterViewInit (fullcalendar-angular.mjs:237:42)
    at ie (core.mjs:2498:22)
    at Y (core.mjs:2467:17)
    at E (core.mjs:2418:9)
    at mf (core.mjs:12082:21)
    at pb (core.mjs:13085:13)
```

by the way i'm using angular 14

Comment: your event data is not coming properly, can you share your console logs?